# Best approach to define overridable settings in django app?

Tags: django

Fairly new to this, I am coding a reusable Django App and I find myself needing the set up many constants that configure how the application works. However I'd like these constants to be overridable by the final user on its own settings.py file.  Which is the best industry-standard approach to achieve this? I need these constants to be available everywhere int the application (models, views, templates, template tags...)

I took a look here but I need a bit more explanation. Thank you.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally opted for a the methodology outlined here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/

My blog config file is apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.conf import settings
class BlogConfig(AppConfig):
    label = 'Blog'                                        
    name = 'blog'                                        
    verbose_name  = "Django Blog"
    pagination = 9
```

My **init**.py is:

```
default_app_config = 'blog.apps.BlogConfig'
```

To read a config property from a view I just need to:

```
from django.apps import apps
def my_func():
    pagination_elements = apps.get_app_config('Blog').pagination
```

To display a config property in a template, I use a template tag defined as:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.apps import apps
@register.simple_tag
def app_attr(name):
    return(mark_safe(getattr(apps.get_app_config('Blog'), name)))
```

And in a template, I just call it like so:

```
<p>This app paginates {% app_attr 'pagination' %} elements per page.</p>
```

The end-user can override any of these settings in their settings.py file like so:

```
from blog.apps import BlogConfig

class MyOwnBlogConfig(BlogConfig):
    verbose_name = "My fricking blog"
    pagination   = 20

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'anthology.apps.MyOwnBlogConfig',
    # ...
]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is not the best one.
settings.py file is not the place where you need to put dynamic content that change frequently. Also you will need to restart the webserver each time content will change.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I mean things like pagination elements, options such as display social sharing or not...etc. How would you implement it?

Comment: create a config model on your models.py and use it for each django app

Answer (score 1):

We're using following settings class in our libraries:
https://github.com/druids/django-pynotify/blob/master/pynotify/config.py

It holds configuration defaults for the library, but also loads project's settings for possible overriding of the default values. The only difference is, that you always read library settings through this class. I.e. you do:

```
from .config import settings
```

instead of:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

Feel free to use that class if it fits your needs.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Could you please provide an example about how any of these constants could be overriden in the local settings.py file of the user? :)

Comment: Sure, you just need to join defined prefix and name of the constant. Given the class I linked to, it has for example setting called `ENABLED` (which is by default True) and prefix `PYNOTIFY` (name of the library). In order to override this value to False, you define `PYNOTIFY_ENABLED = False` in project settings. When you then read the value in your code, you don't use the prefix, but just `settings.ENABLED`. The prefix is there only to isolate library specific settings (prevent name clash)  from other project settings.